# Where are the sources for the Secure module?

Tags: java, playframework

I have Play 1.2.3, and using IntelliJ to view it.

Everything works fine, except the source for the `Security` class seems to be missing.
I searched through the local Play source folder, and haven't found it.

The application seems to find it somewhere though. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All modules are intalled in the `%PLAY_HOME%\modules` directory.

For the Security class source it will be : `%PLAY_HOME%\modules\secure\app\controllers\Secure.java`.

Comment: also, once you have run `play deps` in your project, you should be able to find the module and its source code under <project path>/modules too.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a known issue that the sources are not visible in IntelliJ?

Comment: I believe running `play idealized` again is required after adding the module - I dunno if I missed this or not, but it best if its  documented here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/ide

Comment: It's the case with Eclispe, the procedure to add a module is :
1. Add it in dependencies.yml
2. run "play dependencies" on the project
3. re-run "play eclipsify" (and refresh the project 2 times in eclipse)