# How do I make the logout action redirect to a specific page in Play?

Tags: java, playframework

I am using a custom Security controller that extends Secure.Security.

Currently the "logout" action leaves me at the login page. How can I redirect it to another page? This doesn't work:

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {
    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        User user = User.find("byUsername", username).first();
        return user != null;
    }

    public static void logout() {
        Application.index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer once I found where the [sources for the Secure class are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153964/where-are-the-sources-for-the-secure-module/8154061#8154061).

```
public static void onDisconnected() {
    Application.index();
}
```